# New signal arrives while execution is in a signal handler, how to decide which is first?

Tags: linux, signals, posix, glibc, parallelism

I am working on a tool handling a massive amount of signals (with *different* signums) with `sigaction()`.

I need to handle the case, if a new signal is coming, while the previous was in a signal handler. Thus, I need to be able to handle the following "stack":

1. normal flow of the process
2. handler of *signal1*
3. handler of *signal2*
4. ...possibly further signal handlers...

(Afaik there is no real stack, because signal handlers run in their own context, but this is how I can illustrate my question.)

I am using the glibc2 api.

The problem is not hopeless (I can pass the signal infos to reentrant data structures in the main process to be processed later, from the main execution flow), but *I need a reliable way to find out from a handler, if it is the first on the "stack" or not.*

Masking signals is not okay, minimizing the loss of signals (f.e. from conflation) is a top priority.

I need *reliable* way. Using a global sigatomic_t as spinlock is also problematic, because I can't guarantee that a new signal isn't coming just after the beginning of *signal1* handler (yet before the try to acquire the lock).

After digging a lot in manuals and glibc docs, I didn't find any reliable way to for a signal handler to find out, if he is the first or not. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but maybe use `sigaltstack` to make all your signal handlers get called on an alternate stack. The first signal handler ought to have its stack pointer at a known spot (at the top of the alternate stack; experiment to see where it is on your arch) every time.

Comment: Another option that may work for you if you're worried about not being able to react to signals quickly enough is to use `signalfd`. Rather than being hammered by lots of signal handler invocations, you can set things up so a single `read` can consume all your pending signals.

Comment: `zsh` includes a queue for signals last I looked, maybe see how they implemented that? (under `Src/signals.c`)

Comment: @thrig I checked. They are using a circular queue for the "pending" (it is NOT the kernel-side pending) signal handlers, just as me. But they couldn't avoid to use a short signal blocking section. It isn't a good omen :-(

Comment: @MarkPlotnick First is good idea, now I am thinking if it is usable to avoid the signal loss.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `man signalfd` isn't clear about the masking of the pending, but not yet read signals. I have a strong impression, that they are blocked. There is no SA_NODEFER as in `sigaction`.

Comment: What's your architecture? Perhaps there are some assembler constructs that you could use.

Comment: @Ángel amd64. If I could dereference pointer _and_ move data into it atomically (i.e. _atomical_ `*p=act`;), would be a big help. Extending it with an incremention (`*(p++)=act`) could give trivial solution.

Comment: You also need to increment the pointer, ie. `*p++=act` Otherwise a concurrent signal would overwrite it.

Comment: @Ángel Yes. :-) But afaik there is no super-cisc architecture which could do this from a single cpu instruction.

Comment: `push act` would provide the atomic `*(p++)=act` you want. But then, you don't have a stack anymore. ☹

Comment: I keep thinking that you're [using the wrong tool for the job](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but it's difficult to tell since I've only seen one part of your architecture. If you want reliable communication, use pipes or sockets, not signals.

Comment: @Gilles Realtime signals can do the task correctly, this is what I want with normal signals, too.

Comment: @Gilles I have discovered a truly marvellous algorithm of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current best idea. A little bit of thinking is yet back, but I am sure it will work.

The trick is: the `atomic_swap` and a global pointer (call this `SigAction* top`). It serves as *both of spinlock and as the pointer to the last element of the signal stack.*

Thus:
* if `top == NULL`, `atomic_swap(top, myPointer)` acquires the lock.
* if `top != NULL`, `atomic_swap(top, myPointer)` puts myPointer into top, while myPointer will have the previous top element of the stack.
* The stack is a chained list, every `myPointer->next` contains its next element.

```
SigAction* top = NULL;

void handler(SigAction* action) {
  SigAction bkp;

  restart:

  bkp = action;
  atomic_swap(&top, &action);
  if (!action) { // we acquired the lock
    run_handler(action);
    atomic_swap(&top, &action); // release the lock
    if (action!= bkp) { // if there is a new element in the stack
      action = bkp->next;
      goto restart;
    }
  } else { // the lock is not ours
    action->next = bkp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Configure your signal handler as masking the signals, then unmask after annotating that you received this signal.

```
volatile_t sig_atomic_t signal_count;
void mysignalhandler(int signo) {
   sig_atomic_t depth = ++signal_count;
   pending_signals.push(signo)
   if (depth > 1) return;
   sigprocmask(<unblock all signals>)

    while (!pending_signals.empty())
       /* Process pending_signals */
}
```

Note there's a small race condition between the last pending_signals.empty() check and the iret. If you were going to have some check in the main code, I'd leave it as that, given your sheer number of signals, it will probably e processed soon anyway. Otherwise, you can clock again the signals at the end, and check pending_signals is still empty before returning.

Comment: Thank you, but I cite from my question: *"Masking signals is not okay, minimizing the loss of signals (f.e. from conflation) is a top priority."*.

Comment: I **am** minimizing that. You are only masking them for 2-3 cycles. With absolutely no masking, you won't be able to detect a signal twice.

Comment: This is partially research project and the intention is to solve the problem _without_ masking. A single context switch was 120 cycle as I last time measured it (I measured by calling `getpid()` around 1e+9 times).

Comment: I thought you were running in some kind of microcontroller. If you were running in ring 0, `cli` and `sti` would be about 1 cycle each.

Comment: Finally I found a purely atomical solution!!! The trick of the recursive algorithms, that you need to have a _very_ few global variables (in my example, this is 1 (!!!) ), and you have to "talk" through them exclusively through atomic operations. But anyways, thank you very much thinking together!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach:

You may receive many different signals, but there's a finite set of signals. Also, we don't care too much about the order they arrived, so we can simply count the number of signals we received:

```
long signals[SIGRTMAX];
int signal_handler(int signum) {
    signals[argc]++;

    /* Locklessly process the contents of signals */
}
```

`gcc -O1 -masm=intel` transforms it into a single instruction:

```
add QWORD PTR signals[0+rdi*8], 1
```

although it may need a `LOCK` prefix in case there are several cores and threads.

Comment: [This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) is what I see, and see currently...

Comment: By me it makes `mov rax, rsi / mov QWORD PTR [rdi], rsi`, although I've made `*(p++)=q`.

Comment: It seems to me, `__atomic_compare_exchange` can do an atomic `(a==b)?(a=c):(b=a)`. Next questions: 1) does it really work, I check the asm 2) how will I have a reentrancy-safe pendingsignal array from that.